# JWPlayer default resolution

Tags: video-streaming, jwplayer, jwplayer7

I am fairly new to JWPlayer, but I like it. I am using their free cloud hosted version and it works quite well. However, when wanting the default streaming quality to be something other than 360 (like 720), every help article on their site points to [This](https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1428524-hd-quality-toggling) article. Everything there looks like it is for self hosted, and I am not quite sure what to do. Literally the only code I have included for the cloud hosted to work is:

```
<script src="//content.jwplatform.com/players/<somestringpath>.js"></script>
```

Which is nice, but it looks nothing like their examples :)

Comment: Cant you setup the player with https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1413113-configuration-options-reference for the free cloud hosted version?

Comment: Running into the same problem. It's weird that the default embed code has no settings for resolution!

Comment: Hey @lapinkoira, I just did not know where to put the extra "overrides" code. I did not see in that article where to put it, but I found another article (in my answer) that told me how/what to put in the head element of the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, FINALLY found what I needed. It seems JWPlayer (which is awesome btw) has a Cloud Hosted version, and sort of an *advanced* Cloud Hosted version. With the easy version, one simply includes:

```
<script src="//content.jwplatform.com/players/<CUSTOM VIDEO ID>.js"></script>
```

where they want the video to appear. For the advanced version, the *player* code is inserted into the head tag, and then additional "overrides" can be implemented.

```
<head>
 ...
 ...
 <script src="//content.jwplatform.com/libraries/<CUSTOM PLAYER ID.js"> </script>
 ...
</head>
<body>
...
...
<div id="jwAerialVideo"></div>
<script type="text/JavaScript">
    var playerInstance = jwplayer("jwAerialVideo");
    playerInstance.setup({
    //Placeholder Image
    image: "//content.jwplatform.com/thumbs/<CUSTOM IMAGE ID>.jpg",
    sources: [{
        file: "//content.jwplatform.com/videos/<CUSTOM VIDEO ID>.mp4",
        label: "360p SD"
      },{
        file: "//content.jwplatform.com/videos/<CUSTOM VIDEO ID>.mp4",
        label: "720p HD",
        "default": "true"
      },{
        file: "//content.jwplatform.com/videos/<CUSTOM VIDEO ID>.mp4",
        label: "1280p HD"
      }]
    });
</script>
...
</body>
```

This allows for me to specify a custom placeholder image and set the default video quality to 720px.

The two articles used to as references to do this are [Here](https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/en/portal/articles/1406723-basic-video-embedding-options#fndtn-method-1) and [Here](https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1430240-hls-adaptive-streaming)

NOTE: One thing in their instructions that is not correct anymore is that to find the custom video ID's for each quality of video, in the dashboard go to Content-->Videos-->*Select your video*-->Sources Tab. This as of JWPlayer 7.